# Does anyone know of a really good client/server tcp/udp terminal utility, for windows?

Tags: debugging, tcp, udp

I would like a utility that would allow me to send/receive tcp and udp messages as a client or server, assemble packets, set responses, etc...  Preferably on Windows.  Please let me know if you've seen anything like this.  THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use ["Hercules SETUP Utility"](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html) for this. It looks too simple at first blush, but it is the the very useful utility indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try the TcpClient and TcpListener in System.Net in one of the .NET languages? It is very simple to use these classes to implement a client/server system for your own.

Comment: I was hoping someone else had already done that work.  That's my last resort.

Comment: It's a very generic utility you are talking of, which, IMHO doesn't fall in any specific category. Hence, I suggested that resort.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following with the free evaluation version (no time limit) of [Docklight Scripting](https://docklight.de/docklight-scripting-simulating-and-testing-tcpudp-applications/) on Windows:

- Send/receive ASCII or binary messages to/from a TCP server.
- Be a TCP server and accept one incoming connection, then again being able to receive and send TCP messages. Including sending out automatic answers / reactions to incoming data.
- Act as a UDP peer and send/receive UDP messages.

Another freeware solution that I didn't try myself, but looks really good is [Packet Sender](https://packetsender.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [YAT Terminal](https://sourceforge.net/projects/y-a-terminal/). It could process TCP/UDP/Serial communication. Nice setup for macros to send with hotkeys and buttons

Answer (score -1):

```
//Server Binding

IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 2015);
serverSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);

//Begin Recceive from any client
IPEndPoint ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;
serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender, new AsyncCallback(OnNetworkBytesReceived), epSender);


private void OnNetworkBytesReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
{
   IPEndPoint ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
   EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;
   int BytesRead = serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epSender);
   //parse your data
   ParseNetworkBytes(BytesRead, epSender);
   serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref    epSender, new AsyncCallback(OnNetworkBytesReceived), epSender);

}//OnNetworkBytesReceived()

//for sending to client
Byte[] byteDataTemp = msg.messagePacketByLength(i, Constants.MAXSENDBUFFERSIZE);
serverSocket.BeginSendTo(byteDataTemp, 0, byteDataTemp.Length, SocketFlags.None, epRcvr, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null);


private void OnSend(IAsyncResult ar)
{ 
    try
    { 
        lock (serverSocket)
        { 
            serverSocket.EndSendTo(ar);
        } 
    } 
    catch (ObjectDisposedException objexp)
    { 

    } 
    catch (Exception exp)
    { 

    } 
}//OnSend()
```

Comment: You should probably add an explanation here as well as just adding the code.